# Tapestry: How to create stacked JqPlotBar chart with String label on x-axis

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart, tapestry

I can create a stacked JqPlotBar chart using XYDataItem. However, I need the x-axis to be labels, such as Agent A, Agent S etc. I have tried using TextValueDataItem but the bar chart is not showing. How can I create a stacked JqPlotBar chart with string labels on the x-axis?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I continue using XYDataItem. I then use params parameter to include the option ticks, which would show the label on x-axis. 
Here is the code fragment.

```
JSONObject axes= new JSONObject();
JSONObject xaxis= new JSONObject();
xaxis.put("renderer",  new JSONLiteral("jQuery.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer"));

JSONArray ticksArray = new JSONArray(); 
ticksArray.put("Test1");
ticksArray.put("Test2");
xaxis.put("ticks", ticksArray);
axes.put("xaxis", xaxis);
json.put("axes", axes); 

options.put("options", json);
return options;
```